# Backup functions before change or delete in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "store_backup" (
  "id" serial,
  "functionname" varchar(100),
  "functionscript" text COLLATE,
  "backupuser" varchar(20),
  "backuptime" timestamp(6) DEFAULT now()
)
;
```

How can save the DDL of function before it is changed or deleted on the table?

Comment: Many people would just choose to version the DDL relevant to the database schema.  Any reason you can't do that?

Comment: My stored procedures are frequently changed by many people, and I want to save the previous versions to return when they are wrong.

Comment: I recommend using version control for this, Git should be workable.